# Why does JScrollPane with JList disappear when the JList becomes empty after last remove element?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

I have a JPanel using a BorderLayout Jlists EAST, WEST, CENTER, and SOUTH. When I remove all the elements (now making it empty) from the SOUTH JList and the UI repaints ... either from manually call to repaint(), changing focus to another window then coming back, or min/max'ing the window, etc ... the JList just disappears from view.

As a result, I am unable to drag and drop elements from the other showing JLists into the SOUTH JList because it is not showing ... very annoying.

How do I get around this?

Code:

### Main.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    private ExampleList westItems;          
    private ExampleList eastItems;
    private ExampleList southItems;         
    private ExampleList centerItems;

    public Main(){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {                     
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                JPanel mainPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

                westItems = new ExampleList();              
                eastItems = new ExampleList();
                southItems = new ExampleList();         
                centerItems = new ExampleList();

                mainPane.add(westItems, BorderLayout.WEST);
                mainPane.add(eastItems, BorderLayout.EAST);
                mainPane.add(southItems, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                mainPane.add(centerItems, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                JButton addButton = new JButton("Add Items");
                addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                            westItems.addItem(new String("West "+i));
                            eastItems.addItem(new String("East "+i));
                            southItems.addItem(new String("South "+i));
                            centerItems.addItem(new String("Center "+i));
                        }
                    }
                });

                JButton removeFromSouthButton = new JButton("Remove South Item");
                removeFromSouthButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        // Remove the last element
                        int count = southItems.getModel().getSize();
                        if( count > 0 )
                            southItems.removeItemAt(0);
                    }
                });             

                JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
                buttonsPanel.add(addButton);
                buttonsPanel.add(removeFromSouthButton);

                contentPane.add(mainPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                contentPane.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.repaint();                
            }
        });

    }
}
```

### ExampleList.java

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class ExampleList extends JList {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DefaultListModel<String> model;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ExampleList() {

        model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        setModel(model);
        setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        setVisibleRowCount(1);        

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Example List"));

        setFixedCellWidth(150);
        setFixedCellHeight(150);
    }

    public void removeAllElements(){
        model.removeAllElements();
    }

    public void removeItem(String item) {
        model.removeElement(item);

    }

    public void removeItemAt(int index) {
        model.remove(index);

    }

    public void addItem(String item) {
        model.addElement(item);

    }

// End Mouse Listener Stuff
}
```

Comment: `"How do I get around this?"` -- By first showing us code, preferably a [minimal compilable runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Seriously -- without code, it's anyone's guess what you could be doing wrong. We don't want to see your whole program or a ton of unrelated code, just a small compilable runnable program that has just enough code to allow it to run and demonstrate for us your problem. Please click on the link in my first comment to see exactly what you will want to create and post for us.

Comment: I'll add the code, but it's an issue with Java I'm sure.

Comment: No, Java is behaving as it's supposed to. Rather its an issue with your understanding of Java. But we can't help you without seeing what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I now added the code. If you run it you will see that if you click the 'Add' button on the bottom it puts some items into each JList. Then if you DnD all the items out of the south list the entire south list disappears from view so I can't drag items back into it. And the strange thing is that it only appears to be an issue with the south list and not any other list when this happens.

Comment: Please re-read the link in my first comment. You've posted too much code, most of it completely unrelated to your problem, too much to ask volunteers to go through.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if it's because of DnD so I had to include that part of the code. And I think it has to do with 4 lists, one being south. And I've already made a separate example with way less code than my actual project just to show the example.

Comment: I removed the DnD stuff now to make it less code.

Comment: This is exactly how to works. As you remove elements from a list, it's preferred size changes, as it's preferred size changes, the layout manager is notified and the layout is updated, shrink your lists.

Comment: What does shrink my lists mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered properly and I figured it out. If you don't do a "setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height))" then once there are no more items in the list it will simply just be width=0 and height=0. If you do call setPreferredSize() with any non-zero values then it will display.

I did this and it worked:

southItems.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));